# How to sum two columns in Laravel 5.6

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a SQL query and I want to convert it to eloquent.
My query that I know that it works is:

```
SELECT DISTICT(excavatorId), SUM(times_loaded), SUM(litres) FROM daily GROUP BY excavatorId;
```

and it returns the following result:

```
+-------------+-------------------+-------------+
| excavatorId | sum(times_loaded) | sum(litres) |
+-------------+-------------------+-------------+
|          55 |               179 |         168 |
|          60 |                50 |          50 |
+-------------+-------------------+-------------+
```

Now in Laravel i try the following:

```
$result = DB::table('daily as d')
                ->select([
                    'excavatorId',
                    'times_loaded',
                    'litres'
                ])
              ->groupBy('excavatorId')
              ->where('date', $request->input('date'))
              ->sum('d.times_loaded', 'd.litres');
```

This query only returns a string that has the value "179" only.
What is the correct way to do this in Laravel and have the result of the SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use DB::raw() to make database operations without retrieving all data.

```
    $result = DB::table('daily')
          ->select([
                'excavatorId',
                DB::raw("SUM(times_loaded) as total_times_loaded"),
                DB::raw("SUM(litres) as total_liters"),
            ])
          ->groupBy('excavatorId')
          ->where('date', $request->input('date'))
          ->get();
```

You don't need to use `daily as d` as you are not joining two tables so that you may need a table reference.

Please find the reference [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions)

Comment: That's nice! Thank you!  But strangely enough this returns the following: [{"excavatorId":55,"total_times_loaded":0,"total_liters":0},
{"excavatorId":60,"total_times_loaded":0,"total_liters":0}]  Those zeros are strange

Comment: OK I got it. I had to remove the character ' inside the parenthesis of SUM like:   DB::raw("SUM(times_loaded) as total_times_loaded"), instead of   DB::raw("SUM('times_loaded') as total_times_loaded"),

Comment: Okay I will edit the answer accordingly, for future references